# line-height in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a bit of clarification regarding `line-height` in `css` .I tried the following code:

```css
.red {
  line-height: 4.1;
  border: solid red;
}

.box {
  width: 18em;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box red">
 <div>Avoid unexpected results by using unit-less line-height</div>
  length and percentage line-heights have poor inheritance behaviour ...
</div>
```

In the example above , I havent used `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` ,but still I am able to see the spacing between the text .Why is it?

Also , I have one more clarification : when I apply `line-height : 25em;` on an `inline-block` element say `<div style="display:inline-block;line-height : 25em;"></div>` ,
 will the space occupy on **top** and **bottom** of this element with respect to its parent **or** the spacing will occur for the inline elements of its children?

Comment: what do you want  plz clearly in your question

Comment: @Sumitpatel: mdn document says  line-height works on inline and inline-block elements only , in my example I have not used but still it works, I wanted to know about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the example above , I havent used display:inline or
>   display:inline-block ,but still I am able to see the spacing between
>   the text .Why is it?

An element inherit `line-height` from its parent, no matter it is an `inline`/`inline-block`/`block`, but as you can see below, a `block` element behaves different than an `inline`, where the `block` element itself is not affected (no space between the div elements) but its content is.

```css
body {
  line-height: 4;
}
div, span {
  background: lightblue;
}
div + div, span + span {
  background: lightgreen;
  line-height: 3;
}
div + div + div {
  background: lightgray;
  line-height: 2.5;
}
```

```html
<span>
  This is a sample text inside a span element<br>
  that has a line break making this come in 2 lines
</span>

<span>
  This is a sample text inside a span element
</span>

<div>
  This is a sample text inside a div element<br>
  that has a line break making this come in 2 lines
</div>

<div>
  This is a sample text inside a div element
</div>


<div>
  <span>
    This is a sample text inside a span element<br>
    that has a line break making this come in 2 lines
  </span>

  <span>
    This is a sample text inside a span element
  </span>
<div>
```

> When I apply line-height : 25em; on an inline-block element say `<div
>   style="display:inline-block;line-height : 25em;"></div>` , will the
>   space occupy on top and bottom of this element with respect to its
>   parent or the spacing will occur for the inline elements of its
>   children?

For its children

```css
div:nth-child(2) {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 4;
  background: lightgreen;
}
div:nth-child(1),
div:nth-child(3) {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  This is a sample text displayed as block
</div>
<div>
  This is a sample text displayed as inline-block
</div>
<div>
  This is a sample text displayed as block
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Line height gives the line the text is sitting on a height value. Think of it as when writing in a notepad. When changing the line heights, you are changing the distance between the lines regardless of whether the sentence overflows onto the next line.

If you are trying to achieve a gap between sentences, separate them with "p" tags and then add padding and or margin to your tags.

```
.p { margin: 10px 0; }
.p { padding: 10px 0px; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello i think the problem in not for line height. I think the main problem is -

width:18em;

Be clear about em. Basically em depends on its parents value. Read this carefully. I think your problem will be solved. If you still face problem then use -

width:100%;